# Keep track of questions by high reputation users by favoriting them

Tags: app, favorite

Some users may prefer to pay extra attention to questions asked by those with sufficiently high reputation. This application aims to make this easier by automatically "bookmarking" such questions, i.e., marking them as favorite.

As a side effect, other users will be able to take advantage of this reputation filter  too, by including `infavorites:userid` in their search queries.

- [GitHub repository](https://github.com/normalhuman/FavoriteBot)
- [Discussion on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266792)
- [Post on meta.Math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21550)
- [Account currently running this script on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/274339/normal-bot?tab=favorites)